# Почему strlen показывает вдвое больше символов, чем на самом деле?

Tags: php

У меня маленькая программка. Пользователь вводит имя и фамилию, а php выдает общее количество символов в них. Но проблема в том, что это число вдвое больше, чем на самом деле.
Причем, если ввожу вместо букв цифры, показывает верно.

```
<form method="post" action="sayhello.php">
Имя:<input type="text" name="name" />.
<br/>
Фамилия:<input type="text" name="family"/>.
<br/>
<button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Файл обработки:

```
$first_name = $_POST['name'];
$last_name = $_POST["family"];

$name = $last_name.' '.$first_name;
$col = strlen($name)-1;

echo "Ваше имя: "."<b>".$name."</b>";
echo "<br> В вашем имени "."<b>".$col."</b> букв.";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для многобайтных символов используйте mb_strlen()

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало.